# Comparing two files

Tags: awk

I have two files

file1:

```
45 789 
46 4546
78 4564
71 546
```

file2:

```
41 456 
46 456
40 465
45 456
```

I would like to compare these files and get an output: if the number in first column from first file is in the first column of the second file print a row from second file that include this number.

Desired output:

```
46 456
45 456
```

It will be something with grep? Thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the first file's column to populate an array of "seen" values.  Then when reading the second file, if the first value has been "seen", print the record:

```
$ awk 'NR == FNR { data[$1] = 1 } NR != FNR && data[$1] { print }' file1 file2
46 456
45 456
```

Rather than using the `FR == NR` and `FR != NR` tests, we could also use `FILENAME == "file1"` and `FILENAME == "file2"`.

Comment: Thank you very much and what is the difference of these solutions?

Comment: The difference is that the solution given will work on any number of subsequent files beyond the first two; hard-coding the file names will only work on two files with the specific names given.  Comparing `NR` and `FNR` is a simple "is this the first file or literally any other file" test.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your shell is bash/ksh/zsh:

```
join -o 0,2.2 <(sort file1) <(sort file2)
```

Answer (score 1):

command

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next}($1 in a){print $0}' file1 file2
```

output

```
46 456
45 456
```

Comment: This code-only answer would be much improved if you explained what and how the awk code is doing.

Comment: This works much like the currently accepted answer; the main difference is that it "short circuits" after filling the "seen values" array rather than testing for inequality of `NR` and `FNR`.

Comment: @DopeGhoti can you explain the awk command in detail … what is actually doing .. and how the file2 is processed in above command

Comment: The `awk` code has two blocks; one which runs only on the first file (when `FNR==NR`, which is to say the record number from the file is equal to the overall record number -- which is only the case for the first file) adds the first value of the record to an array, `a`, and then moves on to the next record without further processing.  The second block (which only runs on files other than the first) looks to see if the first value is in the array `a` and if so, prints the entire record.